# How to to display a specific element (SVG portion) in SVG ViewBox

Tags: android, dictionary, svg, webview, svg.js

I am showing SVG image into Android WebView. I want to zoom to and center display around a specific ecllipse element (SVG portion) of the SVG map/picture. Is there any javascript or css way to move to a specific element (ecllipse) on display of SVG.

ScrollIntoView is not working either.

I tried to find a lot but nothing has worked for me yet. I am desparately looking for a solution.

Comment: You can set the view box of the svg to the voiding box of the ellipse. This will show only the ellipse centered and zoomed

Answer (score 0):

Get the bounding box of the ellipse and set the viewbox to that box:

```js
const canvas = SVG().addTo('body').size(100, 100)
cconst ellipse = canvas.ellipse(10, 20)

canvas.viewbox(ellipse.bbox())
```